# Can messages be intercepted?

Tags: iphone, messages

I’ve sent several text and voice messages to my daughter with no reply. Is it possible that her husband has a way to receive these messages and delete them before she sees them?

Comment: Why do you assume your daughter's husband is deleting them and there's not some other issue, like she's just ignoring them and deciding not to answer?

Comment: iMessage is a very secure and heavily encrypted messaging platform - it was the first to receive end to end encryption. So, it is safe to say that unless she's ignoring you, or you're sending the messages to the wrong person, no one is intercepting them. Call her, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes if her husband has her iPhone and knows her pass code (if one is set) - he could ofcourse review and delete any messages before showing them to your daughter.

If her husband knows her iCloud account details (including password), he could setup iMessage on a Mac or another iOS device to receive copies of messages to review. However, deleting those message on his device won't delete them from her device.